# Pixelated light in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, denoise

I've rendered my final scene but the emitting light from the bulb shows a weird pixelated shade at the base and on the bulb... however it seems like its clear in the viewport render.  Any ideas? Is it the emission node?

View port light looks clearer...

[image]

Final render looks very pixelated...

[image]

Comment: You need more samples. The denoiser can't do all the work. Also, are you rendering at 100% resolution?

Comment: Ahh... I thought 1000 samples would be fine

Comment: The number of samples needed for a clean render varies with each scene, depending on the materials used and the light. Sometimes 100 enough sometimes you need several thousand.

Comment: See also this related answer. Sometimes you can get a clean image without denoising at all using clamp indirect: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/problems-with-denoising-in-rendering/97491#97491