# Best settings for denoising in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, denoise

I am working on a project and I am using the Cycles render engine. Denoising usually seems like a good option but the image does become a little blurry when I use denoising with the default settings. Is there a way I could tweak it so that I could get a crisp and clear image without fireflies without spending hours on the render?

Comment: **There is no magic number that works for all situations**, each scene is different and the denoiser will create different artifacts depending on contrast, detail, and number of samples. My suggestion is that you set a render border on the scene, so that you render only a small portion of the image, and make tests until you find something that works for you before the final full render. If the issue is fireflies you might want to test other solutions that involve no denoising as well (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/problems-with-denoising-in-rendering/97491#97491)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/proper-denoising/98535#98535

Comment: don't rely on denoise to fix everything.  you're better off using Branched-path tracing effectively, simplify, and turning reflections down some, to speed things up.

Comment: I clamped indirect to 3. And I am going to look up branched-path tracing now. And the scene in this case looks much better without denoising I guess. I turned of Multiple Importance Sampling too. This scene requires volumetric rendering too in the world settings so any tips while I use volumetric. Some tweak specifically made for speeding up volumetric rendering?

Comment: The best way to get answers in this site is by sharing information. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.