# Firefles in Glass rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, glass

Every time I use glass material in Cycles render with diffuse or any other material with the help of mix shader, I always see 'fireflies' (small random illuminated pixels). I have already tried removing caustics after following BlenderGuru.

[image: image of a bulb glowing using tungsten filament emitting light]

Comment: Play with the settings for **Clamp Indirect** see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/problems-with-denoising-in-rendering/97491#97491

Comment: Read also [Will increasing samples reduce fireflies?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86635/will-increasing-samples-reduce-fireflies) and [How to reduce fireflies in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles)

Comment: Have you tried enabling denoising? (found under the Render Layers panel)

Answer (score 1):

What helped me most times is increasing the **size of the light source**. At default, e.g. point lamps have a size of 0.1 units, so when calculating caustics blender just has rounding errors, I guess.

Of course, raising the size of your light source higher and higher will produce softer and softer shadows, so you have to play with the values.

Another guess: Don't lighten your scene with objects with emission materials alone – they will not produce enough light. Add standard point or area lights where necessary.