# Lightbulb Filament lighting distorting

Tags: rendering, light, lighting

I have been trying to figure out why when I render my lightbulb image, the light coming off it becomes completely distorted. When I use preview render everything works fine. I have tried various light levels and sampling rates, nothing has changed. I have been banging my head against the wall and tearing my hair out to try and figure this out, please help. PS. I have all my render settings on default. I would post more pictures but it says its over the file limit[image: This is the final render and you can see the distortion]

Comment: At first sight, this looks like denoising artifacts?  could you share your file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: Sure thing: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5840" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5840/)

Comment: What you are experiencing is caused by the denoiser. Small (or thin) bright areas against a darker background will result in those white and black squares. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings/98535#98535 try lowering the settings for radius and strength, and use alternative solutions like no denoise and play with the settings for clamp indirect and clamp direct.

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40040/fireflies-noise-on-glossy-material/40142#40142 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/problems-with-denoising-in-rendering/97491#97491 and https://developer.blender.org/T52802

Comment: Thank you so much, I put the denoiser radius down to one and it completely fixed the problem!