# The Rendered Image has bright white pixels

Tags: rendering

After hitting F12, the rendered image looks pixalated, even if I change the resolution setting to 200%. [image: This is my model.[![But it becomes like this after rendering.]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY3TE.png)

Comment: Increase samples for better render and also increase clamp direct. Both are located in render tab

Comment: White noise is called "fireflies". Read: [Hoe to reduce fireflies in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles) and [Will increasing samples reduce firefiles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86635/will-increasing-samples-reduce-fireflies)

Comment: Play also with the settings for **clamp indirect.** See: 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40040/fireflies-noise-on-glossy-material/40142#40142 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/problems-with-denoising-in-rendering/97491#97491

Comment: Yes, it is the noise I was talking about. Thanks @cegaton!